# Docker: Does –user option enhance security?

Tags: docker

Does it enhance the docker security if I start a container with the --user option compared to starting without?

Does it enhance security to start every container with an own exklusive user?

Comment: It is certainly better than running everything as root.

Comment: It enhances the security but not so much if you don't start docker with `--privileged`. If docker starts as root you only modify system parameters in docker and nothing happens in host, but it's recommended to use `--user` for example, if you use a mounted volume, every change in docker belongs to root also in host.